# Python Programming With Calendar Module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Can I create a program which iterates through dates using Calendar Module? For example: If a person gives an input saying that today is 2019/01/25 and he/she wants to add 10 days to the input so the output should be 2019/02/04 and it should be be marked (Circled) or something which can be easily found out from the ouput's Calendar

Comment: I think, you need `datetime` and `timedelta` not `calendar` module.